# Button side by side

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I try with bootstrap 4 to have a button with another button drowdown to its right

Actually button is displayed on separate row

http://jsfiddle.net/2jx14skv/

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="float-right">
      <div class="button-group ">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="searchSamplings">Recherche</button>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle disabled" type="button" id="dropDownExports" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Exportations</button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropDownExports">
            <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Excel</button>
            <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Pdf</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

how to get them side by side?

Answer (score 0):

Give the div with 'dropdown' class a custom class like 'cust-drop' and give it a property **display: inline-block** :

```
<div class="button-group ">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="searchSamplings">Recherche</button>
    <div class="dropdown cust-drop">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle disabled" type="button" id="dropDownExports" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Exportations</button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropDownExports">
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Excel</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Pdf</button>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

In css:

```
  .cust-drop {
     display:inline-block !important;
   }
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

add **d-flex** to group

```
class="button-group d-flex ">
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="button-group custom-class">
...
</div>
```

css

```
.custom-class {
  display: flex;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pandiyancool/h9uy423L/